# Chained JS calls and this in scala.js

Tags: scala.js

I just have started with Scala.js and try to get a simple d3.js statement to work:

```
d3.select("body").append("svg")
```

To get a minimal working version I have cloned the scala.js tutorial, added d3.js into the index-fastopt.html and added the following code in the ScalaJSExample.scala (borrowed from https://github.com/spaced/scala-js-d3):

```
trait Selection extends js.Array[js.Any] {
  var append: js.Function1[String, Selection] = js.native
}

trait Base extends js.Object {
  def select(selector: String): Selection = js.native
}

object Global extends scalajs.js.GlobalScope {
  val d3: Base = js.native
}

object ScalaJSExample extends js.JSApp {
  import Global._
  def main(): Unit = { 
    d3.select("body").append("svg")
  }

}
```

However this code fails with the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.select is not a function
   _a.append @ d3.v3.min.js:3
```

The fastOpt version of the statement is:

```
 (0, $g["d3"]["select"]("body")["append"])("svg")
```

For me it looks like `append` is called with a `this` that is not the selection and therefore the call within append fails.

The following version of the code works but is pretty cumbersome and non d3 idiomatic as d3 relies a lot on method chaining:

```
trait Selection extends js.Array[js.Any] {
  var append: js.ThisFunction1[Selection, String, Selection] = js.native
}

trait Base extends js.Object {
  def select(selector: String): Selection = js.native
}

object Global extends scalajs.js.GlobalScope {
  val d3: Base = js.native
}

object ScalaJSExample extends js.JSApp {
  import Global._
  def main(): Unit = { 
    val sel = d3.select("body")
    sel.append(sel, "svg")
}
```

Is there a better way to pass the selection as `this` to append which allows me to preserve the fluent interface style of d3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original facade types are wrong, and that is why you have trouble. The definition of `append` should be a `def`, not a `var` of a function type:

```
trait Selection extends js.Array[js.Any] {
  def append(param: String): Selection = js.native
}
```

then your chained call will work and produce the appropriate JS.

Comment: Hahahahaha, you beat me by 5s :P